# Symfony2: one bundle for backoffice and one for the public website

Tags: symfony, bundles

I'm developing a website which has a public part and a backoffice part. My intention is to have this bundle structure:

- Acme/CoreBundle: common entities, repositories, services for both public and private
- Acme/BackofficeBundle: controllers, forms, url... etc of the backoffice
- Acme/FrontofficeBundle: same for the frontoffice

Then modify the app_kernel so the bundles of one or the other would be load depending on a enviroment variable of the virtual host.

Does this make sense or there is a better approach for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is primarily opinion-based. You should avoid asking questions like this on SO. Read help http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Hi Michael, I really don't know to put it. Im not really asking for opinions but if I'm doing this correctly or there is another "standard" way for this approach. How can I ask the question then?

Comment: You would be better off just using security.yml to secure the backoffice routes so they are only accessible by IP addresses on your internal network. Then leave the public ones open to the world. Conditional loading bundles and their assets based on environment gets to be a huge hassle.

Comment: I'll second Michael. [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is more suited to discuss concepts

Comment: thank you, i didn't knew programmers

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with a different approach than the one you presented. You don't need to make this clear difference between backend and frontend. You should organize your code using other criterias than "frontend vs backend".

Let's say you have a shopping cart. So you might need some order, customer and product administration. You will have a frontend and a backend. I think the best practice in this case is, if you take the orders, to create an Acme\OrderBundle. Here you will keep everything that is order related. You can keep the frontend controllers in Controller/ and backend controllers in Controller/Backend/. You can create some services for backend area and keep them in Acme\OrderBundle\Backend, but generally your services/forms/etc. should not know about where are they used on, frontend or backend. The controllers should be used to make this distinction. This way you can create a service for order administration that is used on frontend and also on backend, forms that can be used on both ends etc.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, although I find some problems with this approach. For example, what if in both backend and frontend I need the same url. For example /your-account for the user settings (and backend and frontend use different users)

Comment: You can prefix all the backend routes with /admin/ or /backend/. symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#prefixing-imported-routes

Comment: I know, but I don't want to prefix them. It wouldn't very "elegant". The backend is planned to be in a different domain: backend.acme.com/your-account and www.acme.com/your-account

Comment: In this case, you can use host matching for the imported files: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html#using-host-matching-of-imported-routes